# Could not find a suitable constructor using dropwizard

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

(Dropwizard-core:1.3.12)

Below are my resource,dao and server class. I looked into dropwizard tutorials(https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/hibernate.html) regarding this but not able to remove constructor error

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.mySite.surfService.server.resources.v1.MyResource. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with
@Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
at com.mySite.surfService.server.resources.v1.MyResource.class(MyResource.java:31)
at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.installer.feature.jersey.ResourceInstaller.install(ResourceInstaller.java:46)
ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.GuiceSupportModule -> ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.installer.InstallerModule)
1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
```

Tried @Inject in MyResource also but did not work

```
public class MyResource {
    private final MyDao mydao;

    public MyResource(MyDao mydao) {
        this.mydao = mydao;
    }


    @POST
    @Path("v1/getById")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @UnitOfWork
    public Response getById() {
        mydao.getById();
        ........
    }
 }


 public class MyDao extends AbstractDAO<MyRequest> {
    public MyDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public MyRequest findById(Long id) {
        return get(id);
    }
}

public class Server extends Application<T> {
@Override
    protected void run(DropwizardConfiguration configuration, Environment e) throws Exception {
        ...
        MyDao dao = new MyDao(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
        MyResource myResource = new MyResource(dao);
        e.jersey().register(myResource);
    }

    private HibernateBundle<DropwizardConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<DropwizardConfiguration>(MyRequest.class) {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(DropwizardConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void initialize(Bootstrap<DropwizardConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        ...
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, specify library version you are using and provide error stacktrace in full.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk have added version and stack trace

Comment: Thanks. Error says `Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with
@Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.` so I would suggest adding `@Inject` annotation to your constructor.

Comment: Had tried with injection error shifts to dao class
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.mySite.surfservice.core.dao.MyRequestDao. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at com.mySite.surfservice.core.dao.MyRequestDao.class(MyRequestDao.java:9)

Comment: So do the same with dao class. And read documentation regarding DI in Dropwizard.

Comment: Dao layer takes sessionFactory as argument in constructor, so error is thrown
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
1) No implementation for org.hibernate.SessionFactory was bound.

Comment: Per error message, `SessionFactory` should be present in DI container. I recommend you check your DI config.